# TelosB Mote with MSP430 F1161 processor and FreeRTOS With Eclipse IDE errors troubleshooting

Tags: eclipse-cdt, msp430, freertos, texas-instruments, contiki

I spent lot of my time in basic setup. I do not know why it is so complicated in making a basic program to compile with FreeRTOS If there is any expert in this field please help me to fix these errors.

I dont get an idea how to explain my situation, I am tired after long 2 day trails. I am completely new to this area. so i am giving the screenshots of my errors below.

[image: Errors]

[image: Errors]

[image: I got some kind of warning in this part of code]

Updated:

I will try to express my self more brief,Few days back I started experimenting with TelosB Mote and Contiki OS, that set up was very easy and straight forward, even though I was new to this topic it took me only few minutes to set up complete Virtual System for compiling and downloading the code to hardware TelosB. I was happy to see my small application running on target hardware.

Right now, From more than 24 hours I am struggling to compile code for FreeRTOS using IAR Emmbeded Work Bench, I wasted lot of time over here and later tried to use eclipse, even it did not turn out well. Is it really possible for me to run FreeRTOS Demo on my target Hardware (TelosB Mote - Texas Instruments MSP430 micro controller ) I connect it to my PC using USB.

What I mean by [Eclipse IDE](http://www.freertos.org/Eclipse.html) is here in this link.

As far as I know I am not trying to make a new port, I am trying to compile the [existing port](https://code.google.com/p/msp430xf1611/source/browse/trnuk/EmbeddedFreeRTOS/?r=21). I also tried demo code that is given with freeRTOS

When I mean basic program, I mean demo here in case of FreeRTOS, because in the getting starting guide instructions for compiling demo for target hardware is given. [TelosB datasheet](http://www.willow.co.uk/TelosB_Datasheet.pdf)

[image: TelosB Mote]

The the Problems that I faced in IAR Embedded Workbench IDE are below.

The project settings for target hardware are below

[image: Settings]

[image: Settings for usb]

the errors that I get while I try to download is shown below.
[image]

The Connected USB Hardware that is shown in Device Manager

[image: Detected USB Mote]

Answer (score 0):

When you say Eclipse IDE what do you mean? Is this Code Composer?

Have you taken a working port for your IDE and exact processor and just tried to compile it or are you trying to make a completely new port?

When you say a basic program have you written a task? Or are you just talking about a getting the demo compiling?

We need much, much more information to help.

As a basic principle, you should always take a port that is working or something very close. For example, I ported it for an Atmel Cortex from Studio to Crossworks, but this was fairly easy because both use the gcc. If you've taken an IAR port and tried to get it working with gcc or some other compiler, then it's going to be much tricker than if you have a close-match port.

Comment: Hi I updated question with more information. Please let me know if you require more details.

Comment: OK, there is a port for IAR compilers and I would start with that as even though it's not the best IDE, it's a damn site better than Eclipse. So, I would open the FreeRTOS project that is closest to your chip and get that to compile first. That really, really should be very easy; if you're not getting that to work, you're not opening the existing project correctly. Look at the link below for community ports for MSP430 stuff. I would stress, get *an* MSP430 port compiling first, which is straightforward, then start hacking for your device.

Comment: http://www.freertos.org/Interactive_Frames/Open_Frames.html?http://interactive.freertos.org/home

Comment: I used IAR to compile the demo, it worked well for compiling, but got some issues in this IDE related to downloading it to target, please check I added some extra files

Comment: This isn't a FreeRTOS issue by the looks of it, it's to do with finding the right port/driver for using what is, I assume, a built-in JTAG interface for this little kit. I'm out of my experience as I do all my stuff under Linux, however, the fact that you got all this to work and download with Contiki and IAR (I assume you used IAR with Contiki), I don't understand why it wouldn't load the project for the FreeRTOS port. How *did* you get it to load and debug with Contiki?!

Comment: For Contiki I used [InstantContiki](http://sourceforge.net/projects/contiki/files/Instant%20Contiki/Instant%20Contiki%202.5/) it is very simple when compared to FreeRTOS

Comment: So you've never uploaded anything to your device using IAR? If not, you need to investigate how to do that and I'm afraid I just can't help with that, sorry.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the USB port actually acts as a JTAG interface. A quick Google search would indicate that you have to connect up the FET to the board as in the link below. I don't know whether the JTAG/FET adapater comes with the kit or whether you have to order is separately. Also, you might not even have a JTAG interface. My suspicion is that you used a bootloader over USB to program up Contiki. FreeRTOS is not that complicated and I am guessing Contiki has hidden all complexity from you the way it was installed.

Comment: http://www.flickr.com/photos/travisgoodspeed/3118098839/        This link shows you how to attach the JTAG interface. At least one way anyway! Look through that photostream.